# Render pug page on button click using Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am having a hard time understanding how forms work, especially while using Express. I am trying to get my application to render a new page when a button is clicked. I don't really understand routes in express and am hoping I can get some help.

The page

```
extends layout

block content
    #main
    form(action='/routes/index' method='POST')
    input#creation(type='submit' value='create New')
```

The route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title : 'Pain'});
});
module.exports = router;
```

I then used the premade application express generates. The pug file is called index.pug, and the routes file is called index.pug. The first piece of index.js is just to render the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

You should mention the same '/route/index' in the post route definition also.

Comment: A code snippet would improve this answer.